# How to open URL that is inside of textbox

Tags: javascript, html, url, input, text

So I have tried this one:
`<input type="url" id="textbox" /> <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.location = document.getElementById('textbox').value; />`
What I tried to do was that my site would have a text area where I can write a URL and then once you've pressed "Submit" would go to that site without opening a new window or tab. What mistake I have made?

Comment: You forgot the double quotes to end the string after `value;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<input type="url" id="textbox" /> <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="window.location = document.getElementById('textbox').value;" />
```

Comment: Please do not simply post some code. You should explain what you did and how it solves the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer